# android algorithm blob detection

Tags: java, android, binary, blob

I'm trying to make a blob detection algorithm by my self, but I have a strange error and I have no idea what i've done wrong . Please ! Help me ! 
I'm trying to detect dark blobs from a binary image.Jtvvvtfvvv 8884
Hjbi5fh5
Ovihhhiiifbbooog
Iiiiibbbbbbbbv
Iiiiijcbbb
Ijjjjjvvvvvvvvv

```
         for ( i =2; i < height-1 ; i++){
                     for ( j=2; j < width-1; j++) {


                         m1 = mutablebitmap.getPixel(j,i);
                         m2 = mutablebitmap.getPixel(j-1,i);
                         m3 = mutablebitmap.getPixel(j-1,i-1);
                         m4 = mutablebitmap.getPixel(j,i-1);
                         m5 = mutablebitmap.getPixel(j+1,i-1);
                         d = Color.green(m1);
                         d2 = Color.red(m2);
                         d3 = Color.red(m3);
                         d4 = Color.red(m4);
                         d5 = Color.red(m5);

                         alpha = 255;

                         if( d != 255) {

                             if ( d != d2) {
                                 if (d != d3 ) {
                                     if ( d!= d4) {
                                         if ( d != d5) {
                                             m= m+1;
                                             d = m;
                                             newColor = Color.argb(alpha, d, d, d);
                                             mutablebitmap.setPixel(j,i, newColor);}
                                             else {
                                                 d= d5;
                                                 newColor = Color.argb(alpha, d, d, d);
                                                 mutablebitmap.setPixel(j,i, newColor);
                                             }

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            d=d4;
                                            newColor = Color.argb(alpha, d, d, d);
                                            mutablebitmap.setPixel(j,i, newColor);
                                            }

                                        }
                                        else { d= d3;
                                            newColor = Color.argb(alpha, d, d, d);
                                            mutablebitmap.setPixel(j,i, newColor);

                                            }

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            d= d2;
                                 newColor = Color.argb(alpha, d, d, d);
                                 mutablebitmap.setPixel(j,i, newColor);

                                             }
                            } 
                  }}


                   ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                   image.setImageBitmap(mutablebitmap);

    }      });
                When i run this code ....it shows me something weird
```

Comment: The image resulted it's weird and it's not what i expected to be .... i'd show you some pics ... but i'm not allowed to post photos here

Comment: Saying "it shows me something weird" is meaningless to us. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then rewrite your question.